# How can I bind an object to a SelectItem component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten, react-native-component

Can anyone please help me on this? I'm using UI-Kitten's select and selectiem components, and I need to know how can I bind an object to a SelectedItem component?

I would like to pass some value as a binding object:

```
data={
 (['OPT1', 'Option 1'],
  ['OPT2', 'Option 2'],
  ['OPT3', 'Option 3'],
  ['OPT4', 'Option 4'],
  ['OPT5', 'Option 5'])
}
```

Then, I'll like to render each select's option with something like this:

```
const renderOption = (title: string, key: string) => (
     <SelectItem title={title} key={key} />
  );
```

This option could be populated with a map function:

```
<Select
  style={styles.inputSetting}
  textAlign="right"
  size="small"
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value={value}>
  {data && data.map(renderOption)}
</Select>
```

This won't work because map function expects (value: never, index: number), and SelectItem component doesn't have a "key" prop.

I would need to get the key value and not the display value.

Any help pointing me to the correct direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **index** as key like this

```
<Select
  style={styles.inputSetting}
  textAlign="right"
  size="small"
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value={value}>
  {data && data.map((dataItem,index)=>renderOption({title:dataItem,key:index}))}
</Select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Muhammad, for your answer! That helps me with the map part, but still can't figure out how to use UI Kitten's SelectItem to bind to key/value pairs.

Comment: I was thinking of having two arrays: one for the populated SelectItems and a separate one for the data. Then, search for user's selected value in the data object. However, if two values share the same title (display text), I could have problems.

Comment: sorry I did not understand your comment. i am sure you did not need two array. you can use index as key

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that can be modified is the structure of your data!its a 2x5 matrix in a unstructured format!
and as the `.map()` functions is for arrays so cant use it for , ***There is no native map for Objects*** .but if data structure coming from server is out of your control so you can do something like mapping through keys and values with object methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

i hope it helps

Comment: Hello, Amir. Thanks a lot for your answer ! Actually, this is not a model coming from a server, so yes, I can handle the data in it.

I could use something like this:

data={[
              {key: 'OPT1', value: 'Option 1'},
              {key: 'OPT2', value: 'Option 2'},
              {key: 'OPT3', value: 'Option 3'},
              {key: 'OPT4', value: 'Option 4'},
              {key: 'OPT5', value: 'Option 5'},
            ]}


What I would like to know is how can I bind it to a SelectItem of UI Kitten element, since I can't find a KEY prop in it...

Comment: Dear professor i didn’t work with UI kitten yet unfortunately , but the problem i found was that map data , but i searched for that i found this link https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/927 i hope it can help you @GoldenLight

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work for me

```
<Select
   style={styles.select}
   placeholder="Default"
   value={displayValue}
   selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
   onSelect={(index) => setSelectedIndex(index as any)}>
   {data.address.map((item, i) => (
     <SelectItem title={item.streetNumber} key={i} />
   ))}
</Select>
```